# Синхронизация игрового состояния на клиенте и сервере

Tags: c#, алгоритм, оптимизация, синхронизация

Уже как месяц пишу достаточно сложное ПО. Сервер для MMORPG Fantasy game. Вроде все хорошо идет, но тут задался вопросы касательно производительности и синхронизации клиента с сервером:

1. У меня есть контроллер времени, который вызывает событие каждую секунду локального времени машины. Правильно ли будет, создавать пакет, упаковывать локальное время машины (сервер) и отправлять каждому игроку на каналах. Чтобы синхронизировать `Time` клиента и сервера.
2. Система передвижения. Не как не могу понять как работает синхронизация позиции и поворота объекта. Чтобы при движении, объект (в зависимости от соединения) мог передвигаться и это отрисовывалось другим. Моя версия: при попытки движения, а их 2 типа (с клавиатуры WASD или мышкой по земле) отправлять запрос и упаковывать координаты, туда, куда хочу направляться. То есть:

- Вектор позиции
- Вектор поворота

Обе структуры имеют по 3 `float` значения. И того: 6 `float` по 24 байта от одного клиента, при запросе передвижения по земле. Хорошо, допустим. А как быть с WASD? Нельзя предугадать, куда будет направлен игрок. Создавать невидимую точку, с учетом скорости бега + угол поворота игрока - кажется костыльным способом. Создавать событие, если была нажата клавиша из: W, A, S или D и потом отправлять 3-5 раз в секунду текущее место расположения игрока - тоже не вариант. Можно было попробовать в принципе, но это не CS 1.6. Тут карты побольше + игроков > 1000.

Если есть у кого идеи, прошу, пишите. Любой вариант я прочитаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Синхронизация времени

Вы можете в каждом ответе от сервера отправлять клиенту серверное время. Это позволит не увеличивать количество передаваемых пакетов и не повышать нагрузку на сервер. А так же добавить надежности при синхронизации игрового состояния между клиентом и сервером.

#### Синхронизация передвижения

Первое, что здесь надо усвоить - это то что двигается управляемый клиентом персонаж. Каким образом игрок вызвал передвижение - серверу должно быть все равно. Вы можете конечно разделить логику движения на 2 категории:

- Движение к точке
- 2 события: начало и окончание движения в направлении какого-то вектора (направления, азимута)

Но опять же, зачем перегружать серверную логику обработкой двух типов передвижения? Можно это оптимизировать. Привести оба варианта к "движению к точке" не получится, потому что при движении по вектору конечная точка не известна. А надо ли ее знать серверу? Я думаю - нет. Если клиент двигает персонажа к точке - это то же самое как движение по вектору, просто при достижении точки клиент отправляет серверу сигнал о том, что персонаж остановился, и всё.

Получается 3 типа пакетов о движении:

1. Начало движения + вектор
2. Продолжение движения + смена вектора
3. Остановка персонажа

Сервер может ничего не знать, мышкой управляет игрок, клавой, джойстиком, по тачскрину тыкает - без разницы должно быть серверу. Единственное, что знает сервер - это физику персонажа, то есть с какой скоростью он может и куда двигаться (сквозь стены например не может, за край игрового поля не может).

#### Клиентское предсказание

Так как сеть - штука хоть и надежная, но далеко не всегда. Случаются потери пакетов, случаются и другие помехи. Чтобы логика движения персонажа не сломалась - сервер должен отправлять координаты и состояние персонажа назад клиенту.

Выглядит это так: персонаж начал бежать и одновременно клиент и сервер просчитывают этот бег, и последующую остановку. Если пакеты теряются или возникает задержка, клиент у себя будет продолжать бежать, а так как в каждом ответе от сервера есть еще и отпечаток времени, то даже опоздавший пакет будет воспринят клиентом правильно.

То есть клиент и сервер расчитывают игру параллельно, клиенту это дает плавность игры без сетевых задержек, серверу это дает защиту от читеров.

То есть если игрок сломает клиентскую логику и сделает например персонажа супербыстрым, сервер начнет отвечать клиенту, что он не прав, так как по серверным расчетам персонаж не сможет находиться там, где считает клиент. Визуально это будет выглядеть как отбрасывание персонажа в правильную точку и восстановление его поведения на основе серверных данных.

Другие игроки видят только результаты расчета игры сервером. Следовательно, никто в этом случае не увидит, что читер там у себя локально на клиенте быстро бегает или телепортируется. На уровне сервера это будет обычный игрок. Вот вам и защита от читов.

---

Поищите как работают игры, где физика считается параллельно на сервере и работает клиентское предсказание на клиенте. Методика популярная, наверняка есть много примеров и гайдов. Я знаю где это работает так как я рассказал, но в силу нежелания делать рекламу, не буду называть эти игры.

Comment: Это гениально! Предсказание - все как раз и объясняет телепортацию, в случаи если плохое интернет соединение. Спасибо большое. Буду работать)

Comment: У меня вопрос: как часто нужно отсылать пакет положения игрока в момент движения себе и другим в области видимости?

Comment: @MRXIT Клиент получает состояние игрового поля ровно так часто, чтобы он мог отобразить его игроку нормально. Это творческий вопрос, выясняется в тестировании.

Comment: Существуют программы, которые могут показать диагностику нагрузки сети?

Comment: @MRXIT вы можете сами замерять пинг и потерю пакетов. По скорости ответа клиентов серверу и наоборот.

Comment: У меня еще вопрос: траектория движения я не имею понятия как вычислять и особенно смещать вектор в этом направлении. Поэтому я написал простое движение от точки A до точки B. Тут ошибка появилась, что на клиенте у меня есть дома и прочие объекты, которые игрок обходит как только появился путь. На сервере он просто бежит прямо к точке B. Правильный ли я придумал подход что при движении, я отправляю серверу массив точке (path) ??? А уже на сервере я бегаю по массиву и бегу к каждой точке по очереди.

Comment: @MRXIT сервер должен знать карту, если у вас обсчет игрового поля идет на сервере, сервер должен иметь все необходимое для этого расчета. Логично же? Сделайте карту например из вертикальных стен для сервера, для начала. На клиенте стены могут быть там же, только прозрачные.

Comment: Я слышал о таком. Это GeometryData. Но, навряд ли я смогу сделать систему обхода...

Comment: @MRXIT алгоритмы поиска пути вам в помощь, задача популярная.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Но я даже себе и представить себе не могу, как сервер будет обрабатывать > 1000 клиентов. Особенно искать пути для каждого. Карты очень большие и объектов на них очень много. Даже если как-то занести все объекты в базу, одной unity нужно 1-2 секунды на поиск пути. Это я тестировал, когда я от угла до другого угла пытался просчитать путь. Я думаю, массив point3F будет лучше...

Comment: @MRXIT серверу не нужно искать путь, путь пусть ищет клиент и сообщает серверу, куда он бежит (не точка, а направление). Сервер всего-лишь должен знать, куда клиенту можно пройти, а куда нельзя. И остановить клиента вовремя.