# Как работают онлайн игры?

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d, unreal-engine-4

Всем привет!
Как работают онлайн шутеры, а именно как работает их геймплей? Например PUBG.

В моём представление, они работают так:
Есть сервер и клиент. Каждый кадр отсылается GET и POST запрос на сервер, в get мы получаем информацию об игроках, а в post передаём нашу информацию (Координаты и тд). Но, как по мне, такой способ является очень плохим, ведь даже с +- хорошим интернетом такие манипуляции могут занимать большое время, особенно в шутере, где каждая миллисекунда важна

**UPD**

Всем спасибо за ответы и комментарии, как я понял, то в гемйплее онлайн игр используется UDP протокол, а так-же очень интересная механика:
Игра сама прощитывает траекторию движения соперника, так, например, если игрок двигается вперёд, то в случае обрыва его соединения игра будет двигать игрока вперёд бесконечно.
На первый взгляд такая механика кажется немного странной, но если немного порассуждать, то выходит, что она довольна логична.
К слову, в PUBG, по всей видимости, используется такая же механика, т.к. несколько раз я встречал подобные явления: игрока выкинуло из игры, но при этом машина, которую он вёл, продолжала движение

Comment: Ваша фраза «GET и POST запрос» подразумевает, что игры используют HTTP, но на самом деле они его не используют. Тем не менее, игры действительно передают и принимают информацию о координатах и прочем от 20 до 100 раз в секунду (в зависимости от игры), и на хорошем интернете это вполне работает

Comment: игры используют http. При чем, очень много.  Но не для передачи текущих координат.

Comment: @kovadim, возможно и да, например для открытия кейсов, покупки монет и других рутиных работ с аккаунтом пользователя, где не требуется скорость

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый клиент обладает некоторой информацией достаточной для примерного оффлайнового просчёта текущей обстановки. При отрисовке он пытается угадать ожидаемую ситуацию, а потом синхронизирует её с сервером и если оказывается, что она не совпала, то происходит скачок/лаг.

Comment: Воу, интересно. Но довольно как то это костыльно, в онлайн шутере считайте есть 360 сторон куда может пойти игрок, и допустим, все его действия программа не предугадает, выходит, что для врага соперник очень сильно будет похож на читера.

Comment: а почти так и делают современные шутеры. И да, иногда персонажи прыгают по карте как угорелые.

Comment: нехорошо отвечать на [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1294284/373567)

Comment: @aepot, а я тот вопрос никогда не видел.

Answer (score 1):

В основном все сетевые игры работают по протоколу UDP. Благодаря его архитектурной особенности, время передачи данных минимально, в отличии от TCP, где время может быть непредсказуемым.

Comment: Тем не менее, время передачи UDP-пакетов всё равно сильно больше времени рисования кадра (20-150 миллисекунд в зависимости от удалённости сервера), что для шутеров очень критично

Comment: А ещё в сетях есть неприятное явление [ping jitter](https://help.ea.com/ru/help/connection-quality/explaining-jitter-in-your-game/), которое делает время доставки UDP-пакетов тоже непредсказуемым и может сломать всю игру. Тут недавно всплыла тема о проблемах с джиттером в CS:GO https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-YhKLuEUN0

Comment: Можно добавить, что иногда в играх используются хитрые алгоритмы, котрые рисуют соперника на экране "с некоторым опережением" относительно его последних известных координат, грубо говоря, "кадр нарисовали, теперь ждём, когда данные о его положении на самом деле придут по сети. Если что не так - в следующем кадре подправим"